# jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Как из обычного popup календаря сделать постоянно видимый календарик с отображением времени. Типа этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел прикрутить этот же календарик. Но после этого на сайте перестали работать древоивдный список и ещё пару вещей.

Comment: А какой jquery-плагин вы используете для календаря? Инлайн-календарь есть в jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: пользуюсь я вот этим bootstrap-datepicker.js . Да инлайн календарей много но если вы обратили внимание на изображение выше то там при выборе даты автоматически заполняется input.

Comment: Так в jQuery UI тоже можно так сделать. Я поначалу думал, что понимаю смысл вопроса, а вот теперь понял что нет. А в чем именно нужна помощь? Помочь выбрать другой календарь или починить то что сломалось? Как я понял у вас уже получилось сделать инлайн-календарь. Или не получилось?

Comment: Хотел бы прикрутить вышепоказанный календарь. Но некоторые элементы страницы перестали работать. Так вот мне нужен другой календарь чтоб можно было и выбрать сразу время и все это записывалось в поле ввода. А насчет jquery ui можете подробнее описать как можно реализовать такое ?

Comment: Основная идея такая: https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/Gmxmeo

Comment: Отлично ! спасибо Вам. А как быть со временем )

Comment: Написать функцию для его форматирования или взять какую-нибудь готовую библиотеку для этого.

Comment: Ссылочку сможете скинуть ? если не трудно конечно же